# Find specific value of input field inside a specified td

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html-table

I am adding tr's dynamically to a table.  I have a chosen dropdown in the second td and an input text field in the first.  The chosen dropdown is gumming up the works with using ids and classes.   With this code I am able to change the background color of the exact td with the input field I am looking for:

```
thisObj.closest("tr").children('td:first').css('background-color','#000');
```

What I am looking to do now is to get the value of the input field from td whose background color is being changed in the line above.  I've found code that identifies how to pull the input value from multiple td's but I'm just looking to do one.

Comment: Consider using a CSS class to change the background color, then use addClass() to add that class to the cell. Then you can use a normal class selector to find the appropriate cell.

Comment: The input already has a class, actually 2, but the class will be the same on all the fields being added dynamically and will not solve the problem of identifying the specific td associated with the specific dropdown inside the tr.  Also, I am not trying to change the color, that was just to make sure I was only selecting the specific td and not any of the other dynamically generated ones.

Comment: "What I am looking to do now is to get the value of the input field from td whose background color is being changed in the line above." I understood that to mean that you were changing the color, and wanted to use that color to indicate the correct cell. In any case, @James has answered your real question well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's only one `<input>` in the `<td>`, you should be able to find it using the selector you already have as the basis:

```
var inpVal = thisObj.closest("tr").children('td:first').find('input').val()
```

Comment: @jessier3 Whilst this has worked, take some time to consider what Mike mentioned above - using classes and alternative routes for this type of work does tend to make your code more robust and easier to maintain.